# How to Configure puppet client without node entry in the puppet master's manifest file?

Tags: configuration, amazon-ec2, puppet

I have a puppet master server running in a Amazon EC2 instance.

I spawn EC2 instances and setup/configure instances as puppet clients to communicate with the puppet master.
I have enabled auto-signing of the certificates.

Can I specify in the puppet client which manifest file to synchronize with ?
I do not want to add a `node <puppetClient> { .... }` entry in the manifest file for each puppet client I spawn in the master.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use environments with a separate manifest.

```
[client1]
modulepath = /etc/puppet/modules
manifest = /etc/puppet/manifests/client.pp
```

This would use client.pp instead of site.pp.  And on the client you use --environment client1 or set this in puppet.conf.  If you don't want to use node {} definitions in the manifests, you should think about using an [External Node Classifier](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html).  The ENC would return classes and those classes would be included in site.pp or wherever.  Using an ENC seems like it would solve your issue anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If all your client using the same config, you can use the Default Node mentioned in the document:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#nodes